# How do i select the last <p> of a <div> without id or class?

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to get the InnerHTML of a the Summary in:

```
<div><p>
        <span class="info">Name:</span>
        <p><span>The seven wonders of the mind</span></p>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="info>Summary:</span>
        <p><span>Wonder throughout your mind in search for the seven wonders.</span></p>
    </p></div>
```

Im having trouble getting the span of the summary part.

Comment: first google search https://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: Note that embedded p-tags are not allowed.

Comment: @KesemDavid please note hes not using jQuery, but XPath

Comment: thank you for your help i am very thankful

edit 1:i also forgot to mention i am using the HTMLAgilityPack and am coding on C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with the following XPath expression:

```
//div/p[contains(span[@class = 'info'], 'Summary')]/p/span
```

Let's break it down:

```
//div
```

selects all `div`s in the document.

```
/p[contains(span[@class = 'info'], 'Summary')]
```

selects all `p` children of these `div`s that have a `span` child with class "info" containing the text "Summary".

```
/p/span
```

selects all `span` children of all `p` children of these `p`s.

If you're sure that the summary is always the last paragraph, you could also use:

```
//div/p[last()]/p/span
```

This isn't as robust because it might match other `div`s as well and it breaks if the summary is not in the last `p`.

Comment: thank you, I never thought that the contains can be used like that.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
div p:last-of-type {
    #your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last tag selection of `<p>`by jquery.

```
$( "p" ).last().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

.

Last tag selection of `<p>` inside `<div>` tag by jquery.

```
$( "p" ).last().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

.

Add css class to last tag of `<div>` element.

```
$( "p span" ).last().addClass( "highlight" );//by this you can connect css to last tag
```

**OR**

By Css you can select last element.

```
p:last-child {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

[Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/csSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_last-child)

**OR**

Last `<p>` tag in side `<div>` tag.

```
div p:last-child {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```